# Code first approach not creating foreign key

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create 1-n relationship using entity framework code first approach. Following are my classes

```
public class User
{

    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }


    //public virtual Vote Vote { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Education { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Experience { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

and following is my second class

```
public class Vote
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int VoteID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    //public virtual int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public  int UserID { get; set; }


}
```

the user and vote and 1-n relationship, in my case what I mean is that UserID should be foreign key in Vote table. But when I done creating db with following commands

```
   enable-migrations -ContextTypeName ProfileOne.PO -Force

   Add-migration PO

   update-database
```

I am not getting any foreign key OR column name `UserID`

Any help will be appreciated why I am not able to achieve the result.

Comment: This should create a `Vote` table with `UserID`. But the relationship is 1-n (user has many votes), not 1-1. If `UserID` is not created something else is wrong in code we can't see.

Comment: I would believe in this scenario EF expects a one-to-one relationship. Depending on EF version, the attribute may be ignored as the convention uses the PK as FK in such a relationship.

Comment: This should create the Foreign Key. We're missing part of the puzzle here. Easy enough to create an [MCVE] for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following approach:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Education { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Experience { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }        


    //Navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
}


public class Vote
{
    [Key]
    public int VoteID { get; set; } 

    [Required]
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }  


    //Foreign key for User
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; } 

    //Navigation properties
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

For more information, have a look at [Entity Relationships](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx). Hope this helps...

Answer (score -1):

Modify you're classes to look like:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Education { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Experience { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual Vote Vote { get; set; }
}

public class Vote
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int VoteID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int VoteCount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public  int UserID { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("UserID")]
    //[Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The relationship between 2 entities is defined by the virtual properties, which u commented them.

Comment: No. The attributes are redundant (the naming conventions do the same thing), but *certainly* not wrong. Nor is the `virtual` modifier required.